# M is Borel measurable? $0<\lambda^3 (M)< \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

$M:=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3:x^2+y^2\le z, z\le1\}$ is a paraboloid in $R^3$

I need to prove that M is Borel measurable.
Do I need to do something like this? Because I am not really sure how solve this one.
$F^{−1}(M)=\{(x,y,z):F(x,y,z)∈M\}=\{(x,y,z):f(x^2+y^2\le z)∈M\}=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\le z∈f^{−1}(M)\}$

If anyone can help it would be very much appreciated!

**Addition** also would it be possible to prove $0<\lambda^3 (M)< \infty$ without explicitly calculating the measure?
Can I use $\mu ((a,b])=b-a$ rule?

Comment: Use `$\le$` for $\le$.

Comment: Also, use `$\in$` for $\in$. In fact, [here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You're better off asking a new question rather than tacking on an edit.

Comment: For the additional question, note that bounded sets have finite measure, and sets with nonempty interior have positive measure.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you expand a bit on that? I'm still a bit unsure on how to move forward

Comment: If $(x,y,z) \in M$, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2$ so $M$ is bounded.  $(1/4, 1/4, 1/2)$ is in the interior of $M$, i.e. $M$ contains some ball around it.

Answer (score 2):

$M$ is a closed set. To see this, notice that $M = f^{-1}((-\infty, 0]) \cap g^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$, where $f, g : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ are the  functions defined by $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z$ and $g(x, y, z) = z - 1$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $(-\infty , 0]$ is closed, $f^{-1}((-\infty, 0]) \cap g^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$ is also closed.

All closed sets are Borel measurable.

Comment: So  if I am given a set: 1) I identify the boundaries 2) write out the functions 3) check if they are continuous and if the boundaries are closed 4) then conclude if the intersection of the functions is closed, if they are is it Borel measurable?

Comment: Well, this technique works in this case because your set is a closed set; the technique demonstrates that it's a closed set.

Not all Borel sets are closed however (or open, for that matter).

Comment: If it is not too much to ask, could you perhaps give an example when it's not closed?

Comment: Consider the set $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2 \leq z^2, z<1\}$; this is neither closed (missing the boundary points where $z=1$) nor open (does not contain open balls around points where $x^2+y^2=z^2$)

Comment: However, @ConnorGordon 's example is the intersection of a closed set and an open set.

Comment: So in this case it would still be Borel measurable, but neither open or closed? What condition could be used to prove it?

Comment: I guess I am asking how to prove it is Borel measurable, one way to show that its a closed set, what are other?